# C# using projection on MongoDB document

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to get only a few values from an document that has been unwinded.

Right now I get all of this, but I only want the values from "reviews"

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ced083857eda00e03b5a5e"), "name" : "Rest2", "reviews" : { "_id" : ObjectId("57ced083857eda00e03b5a60"), "rating" : 4, "date" : ISODate("2016-09-05T22:00:00Z") } }
```

My current aggregate function looks like this:

```
var coll = Database.GetCollection<Restaurant>("restaurants")
            .Aggregate()
            .Match(new BsonDocument { { "name", nameRest } })
            .Unwind(x => x.reviews);
        var result = await coll.ToListAsync();
```

How do you project only those values? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, you can use project like below:

```
var coll = Database.GetCollection<Restaurant>("restaurants")
        .Aggregate()
        .Match(new BsonDocument { { "name", nameRest } })
        .Unwind(x => x.reviews)
        .Project(new BsonDocument { {"rating", "$reviews.rating"} })

var result = await coll.ToListAsync();
```

The result of the above example would output only `reviews.rating` and `_id` field. See [aggregation operator $project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) for more information.

The snippet above was tested using [MongoDB C# Driver v2.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/), MongoDB v3.2 and .Net v4.5

Comment: Thank you! This is much simpler than what I was doing and it works well